# Does spock designed its framework to have verbose unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, spock

Is the best practice on the spock is to add comments beside the block declaration?

```
given:'comment'
    //code
when:'comment'
    //code
then:'comment'
    //code
```

Or is are the comments beside the block declaration are used only in cases that the code cannot speak for itself?

Comment: @Opal I refactored my question, I hope it is better phrased now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there's no good practice. What You need to take into consideration is what You decide in the team You work with - to format and comment the code always in the same manner.

Personally I comment blocks (`given`, `when`, `then`) only if there is something unclear with code - something that might be not understood at once. I also do not indent the code in defined block (block and the code is in the same column). That's all. If something is unclear feel free to ask further questions.